# SSIS: Column Size Not Changing Based on Query

Tags: c#, t-sql, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I have a package. It has a query that feeds into a `Script Component`.

In the query I am selecting a `varchar(8)` column from a table and then I `CAST(myDateCol AS varchar(10))`.

```
SELECT 
    myPK, 
    CAST(myDateCol AS varchar(10)), --myDateCol defined as varchar(8)
    myOtherCol
FROM 
    MyServer.MySchema.MyTable
```

In my script, I am trying to add two characters to the `Row.myDateCol` in `Input0` but I get a `Buffer Error` and it is in the property setter for `myDateCol`. You can see that it sets the property to 8 characters but errors out after that.

What I've done is add an output column with `Length = 10`, set it, and mapped that to the next component in the package but that seems a little silly.

Is there a way to force the size of your input columns based off of the query **OR** is there a way that I can manually force a refresh in case the package is just stuck thinking that I'm dealing with a `varchar(8)` as the `CAST` operation was added later?

**Additional Info**:

```
Row.myDateCol = "20170404"
Row.myDateCol = "2017-04-04" // Errors out
```

Comment: First cast to varchar(10) an then add the 2 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior for SSIS. When you create a data source which uses a SQL query, SSIS will look at your query and build the the metadata for the dataflow. The data source will only recalculate that metadata if you change the structure of your query, for example number columns or their names.

The easiest way to force a refresh of the data types without resorting to renaming columns is to go to the columns page of the data source editor, Untick and then tick the top tick box of the Available External Columns. This will deselect all columns and re-select them and at the same time refresh the metadata. You can easily confirm this by hovering your mouse over the External\Output column names listed in the lower section.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. You da man. Did you discover while playing about or is there documentation on this?

Comment: Trial and error. Too many why is this **** thing not working moments. SSIS has some great features, but Microsoft has done a superb job of hiding them.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the result of dealing with Date(Time) as text instead of the number(s) it is. And I really cannot tell from your question if you want to want to add the extra characters added in at the Data Layer (Sql) or at the Application (C#) Layer.

Casting VarChar(8) => VarChar(10) will still just return VarChar(8) if you don't fill in (pad) that value. You could try a Cast VarChar(8) to Char(10).

Another option would be a double conversion of your column value to Date and then back to your desired varchar(10).

```
SELECT  myPK,
        Convert(VarChar(10), Convert(Date, myDateCol, 112), 120),
        myOtherCol
FROM
        MyServer.MySchema.MyTable
```

Comment: I know that's the problem. The issue is the script has to clean out some dates because of junk data. I can't just `CONVERT` because it may bomb the query due to not enough validation of user input, ie `2/29/2015` is not a date. I'll try your other suggestion and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: So I padded my column with spaces `CAST(myDateCol + '  ' AS varchar(10))` and it still left it as `varchar(8)`. I then changed the name, `CAST(myDateCol AS varchar(10)) AS DATECOL` and it correctly mapped it as `varchar(10)`. This goes for my last question, `manually force`. So, although your answer wasn't the answer, it did get me thinking differently and for that, I thank you.

Comment: I love inherited messes. Maybe make a true `DATE` column (nullable) and try to populate, catch the errors and come up with some standard (2/29/15 => 2/28/15)

Comment: Indeed, messes galore. I like that suggestion though and gave it a shot. `IIF(ISDATE(DOB) = 1, CAST(DOB as date), NULL)` works like a charm. Only thing is I have to log the previous value, which just means selecting the actual value again in the query but then I don't have to extend the string. An interesting side note, after I got the column size to unstick it now changes without issue.

Comment: I take back the side note, it still sticks sometimes and I have to change the name.

Answer (score 1):

So, after some playing around, I found that renaming the column changed the size to `varchar(10)` per below:

```
SELECT 
    myPK, 
    CAST(myDateCol AS varchar(10)) AS DATECOL,
    myOtherCol
FROM 
    MyServer.MySchema.MyTable
```

I then changed it **back**

```
SELECT 
    myPK, 
    CAST(myDateCol AS varchar(10)),
    myOtherCol
FROM 
    MyServer.MySchema.MyTable
```

And the change stuck. I don't know why or how but VS/SSIS somehow never refreshed itself to change to a different type. I assume it has no handling for query changes after the initial query is input unless names/aliases change.

This wasn't just my machine either. Weird.